# Frankie, you all right?

Tags: questions

Is it common to remove auxiliary verbs from questions in spoken English?

the following is a subtitle from The Verdict movie.

> Frankie! Frankie, you all right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Informally, yes, we sometimes drop *to be*.  This is called *copula deletion* or the [*null copula*](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/null-copula).

Mostly it is such a well-known feature of African-American Vernacular English (or "Black English") that it's hard to find mentions of it in other dialects, but the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project describes it this way:

> Null copula is a highly common feature of African American English (AAE). By contrast, other varieties of English, both standard and nonstandard, cannot omit the copula outside of a few very specific contexts. **One such context is questions like the one in (3), where the first element has been deleted:**
>
> **3) You coming to the party?**
>
> Copula absence may also occur in newspaper headlines, such as the one (4):
>
> 4) DIANA DEAD
>   (New York Daily News front page, August 31st, 1997)

Comment: It may be common in AAE, but it is by no means limited to it.  People of any cultural or racial background could be envisioned saying that.  In fact, my initial reaction was that it was dialog I would expect in a movie about Mafia characters.