# "Where you going in such a hurry?" and "Where you are in such a hurry?"

Tags: questions

Is it correct from the native's point of view to say:

1. Where you going in such a hurry?

or I'd rather say:

2. Where are you in such a hurry?

Comment: 1) is fine. 2) Where are you **going** in such a hurry?"

Comment: @Willow, so I could use both the first without the auxiliary "to be" or the second (the variant of yours)?

Comment: What about placing "a" article before "such"? "Where you going in a such a hurry?" is this correct?

Comment: Neither is correct. I  think Willow might have overlooked the missing *to be*.  In standard usage, you cannot omit either the main verb or the auxiliary verb.  Also, "in a such a hurry" doesn't make any sense, because you only use one article with a noun; you're already using one in *a hurry*, and *such* is not a noun.

Comment: I should not be posting!

Comment: 1 could be an example of a null copula. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122452/frankie-you-all-right/122454#122454

Comment: @JavaLatte - That's true, but it should definitely be marked as nonstandard or at least informal.

Comment: Second one could also be 'Why are you in such a hurry?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where you going in such a hurry?

Without the verb *to be* is colloquial or dialectical.

> Where are you going in such a hurry?

This is standard English whether British, North American or wherever.

> Where you are in such a hurry?

This is neither colloquial nor standard, nor grammatical.

> Why are you in such a hurry?

This is an acceptable version.

All of the above is from a native Brit's perspective.